# calculating order total price, at line level, when using dimension tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]I am trying to calculate the order total at an order line level.
If i just use one giant fact table, this is easy, but once i use dimension tables, the order total stops working.

I've tried variations of ALL, ALLSELECTED(), CALCULATETABLE() but none seem to help.

it seems like a standard problem to face, but it does not see that easy to resolve.

Note, i have not enabled bi-directional relationships, as my actual model has a few fact tables and is complex enough already without introducing ambiguity.

I would appreciate a pointer in the correct direction.
A sample pbix with the problem is located [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgldA0VQfPV9hNBFB8dSysvLXrQe4w)

**Update**: relationship (entity) diagram added.

**Update#2:**
I ended up resolving this the (relatively) easy way using calculated columns. 
On the order table i added the following calculated column to get the order total:

```
Order Total = sumx(RELATEDTABLE(Sheet3), Sheet3[price] )
```

Then on the Sheet3 table ( fact table) i added this calc column:

```
Order Total FactTable = calculate(SUM('order'[Order Total]), CROSSFILTER('order'[orderID],Sheet3[orderID] , both))
```

Its certainly not as elegant as using measures, but in my full model there are too many dimensions and time is too short to get this working. Ill play with it in my spare time.

Comment: Can you post your relationship diagram as well as examples of what you are getting versus what you want to get? The PBIX is great to include but, ideally, this question could be answered if that link breaks in the future.

Comment: solution found, added to body of main post.